# Using Curb in Rails for Streaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stream, curb

Is it feasible to use `curb` in rails for managing and processing a streaming API? I have used it before for a one-time request, but haven't seen any examples of using it in a streaming situation. If it is possible - any thoughts on what the code would look like to get this rolling?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if curb is the answer, but you can use EventMachine to consume a streaming API, see example, http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/3/19/consuming_the_twitter_streaming_api/

Comment: Thanks @Rishav. Any thoughts on managing the connection from my app? Like checking for disconnects and such?